# Why is the image overlay not showing in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the following HTML code. I am trying to overlay the image with a textbox. But the overlay is not working. The text is showing up under the image instead of sliding in from the bottom on hover.

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mt-2">
            <div class="containerB">
                <img src="images/test.jpg" alt="test image" class="image">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h6>Headline</h6>
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- JS files: jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

This is how I styled the HTML.

```
.containerB {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
 }
  
.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
  
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    transition: .5s ease;
}
  
.container:hover .overlay {
    height: 70%;
}
  
.text {
    color: white;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: `.container:hover` versus `.containerB:hover` ?

Comment: change color of  `.text{color: red}` every thing seems fine. Your overlay is `white` so you are not seeing `text`